# Приведение обощеннных типов, ограниченных интерфейсом

Tags: c#

данный код работает

```
    class A
    {
        
    }

    interface IC<out T>
        where T : A
    {
        void CC();
    }

    class C<T> : IC<T>
        where T : A
    {
        private IC<T> _t;

        public void CC()
        {
            IC<A> a = _t;
        }
    }
```

Но, если мы сделаем класс A интерфейсом, то упадет ошибка. Почему он не может привести?

```
    interface A // made an interface
    {

    }

    ...

    IC<A> a = _t; // Exception
```

Comment: проблема из-за того, что `T` может быть структурой. Если добавишь `class C<T> : IC<T> where T : class, A` - проблемы с интерфейсом `A` не будет

Comment: @Grundy это и правда помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy ответы - в ответы :)

Comment: @aepot, тут надо хороший написать, почему это именно со структурами не работает

Comment: @Grundy глянул на шарплабе, говорит что неявного каста нет, но с явным кастом работает. Проблема этогл вопроса в том, что автор не указал, какая у него ошибка.

Comment: @aepot, а это да, но ошибка стандартная `CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'IC<T>' to 'IC<A>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`